# Card and Deck: Problem linking classes (environment issues?)

Tags: c++

EDIT: I removed the main from Card.cpp, and run

```
C:\cpp>g++ Deck.cpp Card.cpp

C:\cpp>g++ Deck.cpp Card.cpp
In file included from Deck.h:8:0,
                 from Deck.cpp:1:
Card.h: In member function 'Card& Card::operator=(const Card&)':
Card.h:13:12:   instantiated from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(
std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = Card, _Alloc = std::
allocator<Card>, std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterat
or<Card*, std::vector<Card> >, typename std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Base::_Tp_all
oc_type::pointer = Card*]'
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/stl_vector.h:749:4:   ins
tantiated from 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::push_back(const value_type&) [wit
h _Tp = Card, _Alloc = std::allocator<Card>, value_type = Card]'
Deck.cpp:7:44:   instantiated from here
Card.h:13:12: error: non-static const member 'const int Card::rank', can't use d
efault assignment operator
Card.h:13:12: error: non-static const member 'const Suit Card::suit', can't use
default assignment operator
In file included from c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/vector:6
9:0,
                 from Deck.h:4,
                 from Deck.cpp:1:
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/vector.tcc: In member fun
ction 'void std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_M_insert_aux(std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::it
erator, const _Tp&) [with _Tp = Card, _Alloc = std::allocator<Card>, std::vector
<_Tp, _Alloc>::iterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Card*, std::vector<Card>
>, typename std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::_Base::_Tp_alloc_type::pointer = Card*]':
c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.0/include/c++/bits/vector.tcc:312:4: note: s
ynthesized method 'Card& Card::operator=(const Card&)' first required here
```

I don't know what the problem is. Someone else tells me that it compiled perfectly fine on their computer.   Anybody know what's going on?

Card.h

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

#include <string>

enum Suit {
            SUIT_HEART,
            SUIT_DIAMOND,
            SUIT_CLUB,
            SUIT_SPADE
        };


class Card {
    private:
        const int rank;
        const Suit suit;
        static const char * ranknames[];
        static const char * suitnames[];
    public:
        Card(int r = 1, Suit s = SUIT_HEART) : rank(r), suit(s)
            {
            }

        int GetRank() const { return rank; };
        Suit GetSuit() const { return suit; }
        std::string ToString() const;
        std::string SuitString() const;
        std::string RankString() const;
};
#endif
```

Card.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Card.h"
#include <vector> 

const char * Card::ranknames[] = { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K" };
const char * Card::suitnames[] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spaces" };

std::string Card::ToString() const {
    std::string s = RankString();
    s.append(" of ");
    s.append(SuitString());
    return s;
}

std::string Card::SuitString() const {
    return suitnames[suit];
}

std::string Card::RankString() const {
    return ranknames[rank-1];
}
```

Deck.h

```
#ifndef DECK_H
#define DECK_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include "Card.h"
#endif
```

Deck.cpp

```
#include "Deck.h"

int main() {
    std::vector<Card> Deck;

        for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
            Deck.push_back(Card(i+1,(Suit)((i+1)%4)));
            std::cout << Deck[i].ToString() << std::endl;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try specifying *both* modules on the command line?

```
g++ -o deck.exe deck.cpp card.cpp
```

Edit: Also, using constants that start with _ or __ is technically illegal. For include-guards, I prefer to use the form `MODULE_H`

Comment: "using constants that start with _ or __ is technically illegal. For include-guards, I prefer to use the form MODULE_H " Weird... Someone recently told me that you should use the double underscore in order to avoid possible linking collisions.

Comment: No, that was incorrect advice. You can put underscores at the end, or in the middle, but underscores at the beginning are reserved for the compiler to use. Technically, it's unlikely that any compiler will ever define `__DECK_H`, but they reserve the right to.

Answer (score 1):

You're supposed to compile and link `Card.cpp` *and* `Deck.cpp` together in a single executable, which I presume you don't as both files contain a `main` function :

```
g++ Deck.cpp Card.cpp
```

Of course, you'll have to remove one of the two `main` if you don't want to get into a new linker error.

Comment: I did so, and received a new compile error. See the Edit of the original post.

Comment: @Colton: `push_back` attempts to call the compiler generated `Card::operator=(const Card &)`, but `Card` has some const members : that's a whole new question, please close this one.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by this. If I close this problem what exactly is the new issue? I don't understand why having const members is a problem for the Card class.

Comment: @Colton: I mean you should accept an answer as correct if you believe it answers the question. Then, having a const member is a problem for the `Card` class when you want to store it in a container which requires `Card::operator=` (how do you assign to something which has const elements ?)